# Как вернуть читабельный текст ошибки по ее коду?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Есть представление `unified_audit_trail`, в котором есть колонка `RETURN_CODE`.

В эту колонку записывается:

- в случае успешно выполненного события аудита 0
- а в случае не успеха, записывает код ошибки, например: 1917, 1939, 1031, и т.д.

Есть ли функция, которая позволит по этому коду вернуть читабельный текст ошибки?
Или нужно завести справочник всех ошибок?

Comment: Если вы ищете решение, которое должно работать для любой версии Oracle, тогда лучше убрать метки с конкретными версиями Oracle....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, такая функция есть — [SQLERRM](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/SQLERRM-function.html#GUID-D4468C8F-62D9-42A5-AF72-C1098C866DC5):

```
declare
    type errcodes is table of int;
    ec errcodes := errcodes (1917, 1939, 1031);
begin  
    for i in 1..ec.count loop 
        dbms_output.put_line (sqlerrm(-ec(i))); end loop;
end;
/
ORA-01917: user or role '' does not exist
ORA-01939: only the ADMIN OPTION can be specified
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Comment: Спасибо, ее и использовал :)